# Different front page node depending on logged in?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

How would I go about displaying a different front page node depending on if the user is logged in or not.

For example when a user is not logged in, you would be viewing the About Page.
When a user is logged in, you would be viewing your user profile page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several solutions to go about this

but the easy way out is this module

[Frontpage module](http://drupal.org/project/frontpage)

but you can also make a simple  rule that says that `if the user is logged in`

[Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules)

[Node.js Alternativ solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367522/nodejs-showing-different-content-for-logged-in-or-not-users)

hope it helps you on the way

Answer (score 0):

```
if (user_is_logged_in()){
   drupal_goto('your-logged-in-page');
}
```